# How does chatbots platforms like Chatfuel or Manychat can create Facebook Apps in the backend to serve Chatbots?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, chatfuel

I want to create chatbots platform to create chatbots on the fly like Chatfuel or Manychat or Rocketbots?
How it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

They simply use one app for all i.e. subscribe their customer pages to their existing (approved) app.